# How can I make JRadioButton transparent in particular case?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jradiobutton

I have a couple of JRadioButton: rb1, rb2; which is contained in transparent JPanel p1, and p1 is contained in a colorful panel, named mainPanel.
I want to make these JRadioButton transparent too and here is what I do:

in mainPanel: `mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);`

in p1: `p1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));`

and in rb1 and rb2:

```
rb1.setOpaque(false);
        rb1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        rb1.setBorderPainted(false);
        rb2.setOpaque(false);
        rb2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        rb2.setBorderPainted(false);
```

it's ok if rb1 and rb2 is contained in mainPanel or if p1 isn't a transparent JPanel, but in my case, the outcome is not what i expected: [image: result]

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weird painting artifacts you're seeing are caused by this:

```
p1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

With that the parent container will not be notified to clear it's background and repaint. So if you want the panel to be completely transparent, just use [`setOpaque(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(false)) instead. You also just need to call this method on the radio buttons and nothing else.

`setOpaque` will notify the parent to repaint, but if you want a semi-transparent panel, you have to override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` manually.

[image]

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class Example {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {    
        JRadioButton encryptButton = new JRadioButton("Encrypt");
        encryptButton.setOpaque(false);

        JRadioButton decryptButton = new JRadioButton("Decrypt");
        decryptButton.setOpaque(false);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(encryptButton);
        group.add(decryptButton);

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
        subPanel.setOpaque(false);
        subPanel.add(encryptButton);
        subPanel.add(decryptButton);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        mainPanel.add(subPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: (1+) for using `setOpaque(...)`. You can also check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for cases where you want semi transparent backgrounds.

Comment: thank u so much. I used to a trick to take a transparent JLabel but it's not a right way. thank u again which all my respect!